# How to split data (.dat) file with multiple tables?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, csv

I am dealing with a .dat file that contains several table for a given data.

I've looked at several solutions, however I did not manage to find the correct and related answer to answer my problem.

Here's a small sample of one of the files:

```
         13x8E                    (13x8E.dat)                                  12/21/14                       
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
         ====== PERFORMANCE DATA (versus advance ratio and MPH) ======                                        
                                                                                                              
         DEFINITIONS:                                                                                         
         J=V/nD (advance ratio)                                                                               
         Ct=T/(rho * n**2 * D**4) (thrust coef.)                                                              
         Cp=P/(rho * n**3 * D**5) (power coef.)                                                               
         Pe=Ct*J/Cp (efficiency)                                                                              
         V  (model speed in MPH)                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
         PROP RPM =       1000                                                                                
                                                                                                              
         V          J           Pe         Ct          Cp          PWR         Torque      Thrust             
       (mph)     (Adv Ratio)                                       (Hp)        (In-Lbf)     (Lbf)             
         0.0        0.00      0.0000      0.1003      0.0426       0.001       0.079       0.090              
         0.4        0.03      0.0660      0.1001      0.0434       0.001       0.080       0.090              
         0.7        0.06      0.1292      0.0997      0.0441       0.001       0.081       0.089              
        ...
        ...
         9.8        0.80      0.5192      0.0056      0.0087       0.000       0.016       0.005              
        10.2        0.83     -0.0017      0.0000      0.0045       0.000       0.008       0.000              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
         PROP RPM =       2000                                                                                
                                                                                                              
         V          J           Pe         Ct          Cp          PWR         Torque      Thrust             
       (mph)     (Adv Ratio)                                       (Hp)        (In-Lbf)     (Lbf)             
         0.0        0.00      0.0000      0.1004      0.0427       0.010       0.315       0.360              
         0.7        0.03      0.0659      0.1001      0.0434       0.010       0.321       0.359
```

I managed to do this one by manually splitting based on PROP RPM value, then read the array (2D array), and finally stacked all the arrays to create a 3D array for one file.

Is there any better way to perform this task?

I am going to use this data for my research study, and there are lots of files with the same format. Thus, performing manual input for the whole files seems like a bad idea for me.

The file contains some NaN data, also. Initially. I would like to interpolate the data to fill this NaN value. However, skipping the data might be easier solution.

Here's the complete file: [Sample File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11kQ29QjHPPswPewDpnHpgf382uRz8jor/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Were you able to make any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with files like this before—climate data from NASA—when I was helping a friend with their thesis.

The files had a PRT extension.  I don't know that they are the same, but I bring this up because my friend never should have been given this kind of file in the first place. There was literally a hand-to-forehead moment when some staff learned what my friend was dealing with; the staff then provided netCDF files which don't require any special processing.

But, if this is all you have to work with, we can write a decent parser in a fairly straight forward manner.  We'll read the file as text and process it line by line.

I see some preamble data in the first 13 lines that doesn't really matter, so we'll discard that by just skipping those 13 lines in a little loop.

From there we'll start looping over every line:

- Blanks lines will be skipped.
- If we encounter a line with "PROP RPM", that symbolizes the start of a new table.  We'll parse that line and extract the RPM value and call that the table's ID.

  The start of a table probably also means the definitive end of a previous table, so we'll save any previously parsed rows with that last table's ID.

  We'll then skip the next three lines, and reset our list of row data (discard previous rows) to make way for the upcoming rows.
- The next lines should all be row data, and we'll parse them by column width.  Python's `float()` function can handle numbers with padded whitespace, like `'  1.23     '` and `NaN`, so there's no extra work once we've defined the column widths.
- Finally, we'll be at the end of the file and we'll need to save the last table's rows.

If you're not very familiar with the `continue` statement, I use it to shortcut the loop and make it start at the next line when it doesn't make sense to process the current line any more; driving towards the lines we really care about, the row lines.

```py
import csv


def save_table(table_id, rows):
    with open(f"rpm_{table_id:05}.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=rows[0])
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(rows)


f_dat = open("input.dat")

# discard preamble; skip to data
for i in range(13):
    next(f_dat)

# initialize state vars
table_id = 0
rows = []

for line in f_dat:
    # don't strip line up front, to make reading and
    # setting the column widths easier

    if line.strip() == "":
        continue

    if line.strip().startswith("PROP RPM"):
        if rows != []:
            save_table(table_id, rows)

        table_id = int(line.strip().rsplit(" ", 1)[1])
        rows = []

        for i in range(3):
            next(f_dat)  # skip blank line and two "header" lines

        continue

    # At a row/data line now...
    row = {
        "V": float(line[0:12]),
        "J": float(line[12:24]),
        "Pe": float(line[24:36]),
        "Ct": float(line[36:48]),
        "Cp": float(line[48:60]),
        "PWR": float(line[60:72]),
        "Torque": float(line[72:84]),
        "Thrust": float(line[84:96]),
    }

    rows.append(row)

# save last table at end of file
if rows != []:
    save_table(table_id, rows)
```

With all the tables split up into individual CSV files, I believe you'll be able to combine them into that 3D array.